# Recommendations for lightweight, open-source AJAX library in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

Not a framework or anything, which AFAICS always carries with it a shipload of extraneous, irrelevant (from my POV) support code. I'm just looking for a couple hundred lines of bulletproof JS that correctly implements multiple simultaneous AJAX requests; error handling; and callbacks into my code.

Comment: I'm surprised this question hasn't received more attention as it'd be quite a useful tool to have. We have sizzle for dom manipulation - would be useful to have a similar, super-slick single purpose library for ajax too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at: **[jx - JavaScript Ajax Library](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/jx/)** (minified *lite* version is under 1k)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply download **jQuery** and strip out what you don't like. Then use a minification tool to make the file size even smaller.